# GLSL implicit int to float error yielded at "float to float"…?

Tags: casting, glsl, fragment-shader

The following line in my fragment-shader…

`gl_FragColor.r = curPosition.x;`

raises warning C7011: implicit cast from "int" to "float" but `curPosition` is defined as `vec3` (so it is a float) and `gl_FragColor.r` is … well … a float. so… what's the problem?

Comment: Are you sure it's talking about that line and not another one?

Comment: jepp. if i comment it out, the error is gone. when i do `gl_FragColor.rgb = curPosition.rgb;` it works… :/

Comment: That doesn't mean it's talking about that line; it only means that the presence of the line is causing a problem. Also, what OpenGL hardware are you using?

Comment: GLSL Ver: 1.20 NVIDIA via Cg compiler, Geforce 7850 GS